# Can writing Object-Orientated Code in a Functional style improve performance?

Tags: object-oriented, performance, functional-programming, compiler, comparison

Given a scenario where you have consecutive setters or a series of events where an object is modified, can it be more performant to instead write code in a way where **a new state is returned** rather than **a field within an object modified** due to how a compiler will interpret the code?

e.g

```
obj0 = new_object()
obj1 = modify_object(obj0)
obj2 = modify_object(obj1)
```

versus

```
obj0 = new_object()
obj0.modify()
obj0.modify()
```

Comment: It depends on how you write it.  In theory functional code will scale better, but that does not necessarily mean it is faster.  However poorly written code in either style will still be slow.  You have to identify the conditions you intend to operate under, and what type of problem you are solving.

Comment: Have you considered the form: `obj0 = obj0.modify()`, which is for example what most immutable objects in Java would do.

Comment: Decisions to use OOP or functional approaches are usually not done for performance reasons, but for the ease of producing high-quality code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modern high-performance garbage collectors are built on the assumption that most objects die young, and most objects are never mutated. Your functional version fits into that assumption: the objects are never mutated, and they can be collected after just one line.

Most modern high-performance garbage collectors will not do any heap allocation for the code you posted, except for the last object. The first two objects will be allocated on the stack.

Therefore, it is highly likely that memory allocation performance will at least not be worse for the functional version. (Azul's GC could easily deal with 20 GB/s of temporary garbage objects in a benchmark ten years ago. In 2020, I would expect that to be even better.)

Your code is nice straight-line code that will be easy to optimize. It *might* be easier for a compiler to optimize because of the lack of mutation.

I am not sure it will be faster, but it highly likely will not be slower.

However, as always with questions of the type "which of these two pieces code runs faster", the *best* answer is: run both of them and *see*.

Comment: However, the functional version is likely to involve lots of copying from one stack object to another, right?

Comment: @user253751: Depends on the language you are using. Languages like C# and Java do not allocate objects to the stack. They are all on the heap.

Comment: @GregBurghardt did you read the answer?

Comment: @user253751 or it gets jitted into a bunch of modifying values in registers, where there isn't a clear "lifetime" of any of the objects

Comment: @Caleth there may not be objects, but that doesn't mean there isn't copying.

Comment: @user253751 in the sense that some value comes back out of the ALU, but not in the sense that `inc eax` is a "copy" operation

Comment: Since when does the GC decide whether to allocate on the GC heap? That's the task of the AOT or JIT compiler, after escape-analysis, or the programmer if the language allows.

Answer (score 4):

It would be misleading to make a general statement about such performance comparison: it simply depends on too many factors. Moreover, modern optimisers are really good at analysing the flow of execution.

As a preliminary remark, functional style does not necessarily mean better performance. Without optimizers, a recursive version of a function may be beautiful to write, but might be less efficient than an iterative version because of the call overhead. Modern global optimisers are able to analyse what the code is really doing and in some cases will generate almost identical code for both variants.

But we can dare to make at least one general statement: the functional style, with immutability, absence of side effects, and function composition/chaining makes it easier to identify opportunities to **parallelize** the code. But be aware that no magic is to be expect here either: some very sequential algorithms will stay sequential even if expressed in a functional style.

Comment: In *any* halfway decent, modern language, tail calls will have the same performance as unconditional `GOTO`, and tail recursion will be compiled to the same code as a `WHILE` loop would. So, at least for the case where the recursive version is just a loop, there should be no difference, except in languages that don't provide Proper Tail Calls, or *at least* Proper Tail Recursion. (And there is really no reason to not at least provide the latter.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag that’s exactly what I meant with “Modern global optimisers...generate almost identical code for both variants” (aka recursive and iterative). Note that it‘s not the language that gives performance (language only give expressivity), but the language implementation (aka compilers, optimisers, garbage collectors) ;-)

Comment: Proper Tail Calls are a language feature, they cannot be a compiler optimization, since compiler optimizations are by their very nature *optional*. (They are not allowed to change the meaning of the code, so by definition you cannot tell whether your code was optimized or not.) Proper Tail Calls, however, make it possible to write code that would otherwise be impossible to write if I don't know whether my tail calls will be optimized or not. In particular, Guy Steele has a nice article where he shows that it is *impossible* to maintain object-oriented abstraction without Proper …

Comment: … Tail Calls. Thus, it is important to distinguish between *Proper Tail Calls*, which are a *language feature* that allows you to write programs you could not write otherwise, and *Tail Call Optimization*, which is an *optional compiler optimization* which *may* make your code faster and use less (stack) memory on some compilers. Or, put another way, PTCs basically mean that the spec mandates that *all implementors must perform TCO*. Which is very different from what *most* specs say, which is that they don't care. Python is the odd man out, which actually *forbids* implementors to do TCO.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Is’t tail recursion something that can be easily identified from the flow graph without any specific language feature ? Isn’t this kind of optimization routinely performed by any decent  C++ compiler?

Comment: Tail *Recursion* Elimination for a) *direct* tail recursion in b) *non-virtual functions* is generally easy to turn into a `WHILE` loop (i.e. a `GOTO` back inside the function), yes. And it is routinely performed by C++ compilers. But it is *not* mandated by the C++ spec, so I *cannot* write code that relies on Proper Tail Recursion, because it is perfectly legal for a C++ compiler to *not* optimize it and instead blow the stack and crash the program. Now, elimination of *indirect* tail recursion, and general elimination of *all tail calls* is harder, especially if you don't …

Comment: have one of these options: 1) total control of the stack, 2) `GOTO`, or 3) Continuations. If you have only one of those, you can do it, but if you have none of those, you need to implement your own stack without using the stack of the underlying platform. That is why JVM languages generally *do* support *direct tail recursion* (because the JVM has a `GOTO` that can jump anywhere *inside the same method body*), but they do *not* support indirect tail recursion or arbitrary tail calls. You can implement Continuations/ `GOTO` on top of Exceptions, actually, but that would be sloooooooow.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Worth noting: for languages without formal tail calls, TCO can very often be defeated by deterministic destruction (from what I know, at least CPython, Rust, Swift, C++, and probably others have this). Destructors implicitly run as the last lines of a function, so what looks like a tail call can actually be an assignment to a hidden local var, followed by a series of destructor calls, followed by a return of the local var.

Answer (score 1):

At a fundamental level, code that creates new copies of objects is going to require at least as many instructions as code that modifies existing objects, so it will generally not be faster in absolute terms. The exception is parallel algorithms where lock contention can make some amount of copying desirable. In the best case (as in your example), an optimizing compiler will produce the same machine code for both approaches.

In practice, immutable objects can make it easier for the programmer to reason about side effects (or absence thereof) in the code, and this can indirectly improve performance since you can freely share object instances without worrying about them accidentally getting modified. However, this depends very much on your problem domain: if you are dealing with large amounts of data that constantly need to be updated, you are likely to incur a performance penalty if you create new copies every time.

Comment: If the code spends a lot of time with locks over contested access, then the copies could actually be faster.  I once analyzed "parallel" code that spent more time fighting over contention than it gained via running in parallel.

Comment: @user949300: That's a valid point, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking types that aren't trivially-copyable, like persistent data structures, even my best attempts to profile and tune them have them 2-3x slower for writes and around 15-50% slower for reads in C to make them immutable and persistent compared to mutable alternatives depending on the data structure (ex: our persistent version of `std::vector` in C++ -- random-access sequence -- is about 2x slower for writes and 15% slower for sequential reads, and about twice as slow for random-access reads with a collection of small types like 32-bit `int` or SPFP `float`). For trivially-copyable types, like PODs, probably (although not certain) it's usually going to make little difference -- best to measure and see but I wouldn't be concerned too much usually in advance if it's just pushing and popping trivially-copyable types to/from the stack until there's a measured reason to be.

I could see some cases where a pure function *might* (just might) outperform one that accepts a mutable pointer/ref with C and C++ compilers at least, but mainly due to how optimizers are conservative with respect to pointer/reference aliasing (at least without hints like `restrict`). That's mainly for trivially-copyable types though. With functions that aren't inlined that take two or more reference/pointer parameters of trivially-copyable types, value/copy semantics can sometimes produce much more efficient machine code since the compiler can assume that the function parameters don't alias each other (at least without optimizer hints to tell them they won't).

That said, in spite of the single-threaded overhead in the non-trivial cases (which isn't a trivial overhead as it manifests in one thread), I was more than able to make up for it due to the increased thread-safety with functions that were now pure by being able to safely throw more threads at the problem than I ever could before. For example, I once dealt with something similar to the analogical game loop where the scene updates had to occur before rendering in a serial fashion. Once I started using a more functional style and made those functions pure (and using persistent data structures for cheap copies for the sections that were modified to produce new versions), inputting state and outputting new state instead of mutating shared state, I was able to build a parallel pipeline where the renderer could be rendering the current frame while the update function was simultaneously updating the next frame to render in parallel without either systems waiting on each other. And that translated to enormous improvements in framerates in spite of the aforementioned single-threaded overhead, and without the doubled memory usage that double-buffered game engines tend to have to accomplish the same thing.

I had a case where we transformed a mutable serial set of operations to a parallel pipeline, accepting the read/write overhead mentioned above, and our stress test scene jumped from ~18 FPS to ~45 FPS on a quad-core machine, and that was in spite of both the rendering system and update systems using parallel loops and multithreading of their own with Intel's TBB internally prior to the changes. It would have been really difficult to achieve that, and especially safely, if we were dealing with functions that mutated the scene graph in-place instead of functionally inputting a former scene and outputting a new one.